# config packaging for both systemd and upstart with dpkg

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging, deb, dpkg

I want to create universal *.deb package for my daemon which can works with both upstart and systemd.

I have my app.conf for upstart and app.service for systemd.

For now they are both stored in the top-level of my git repo with sources (and 'debian' folder).

How should I declare them inside package? Should I install them both regardless of used init system, or should I try to guess init system in post-inst stage?

Or there are some built-in ways to say 'hey, I have config for {{your init}}?'

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the system is `init` with `ps -p 1 -o =comm` and then decide should I ALSO have to install the unit file or not. A little hack I use is to have the content of the unit file in a variable and dump it depending on the condition above. Note that this way requires you to manually handle the upgrade and removal of the unit file, but I don't know a better solution.